# How do you de-duplicate compatibility code in Python where a group of functions can accept different input types?

Tags: python, dry

I am working on a codebase where many functions expected either an integer or a list of integers as the input. We'd like to support both if possible.

This is leading to a lot of duplicated code, and an occasional bug when that code is missing.

```
def get_usernames(userIds:list[int])->pd.DataFrame:
   if isinstance(userIds, int): userIds=[userIds]
   ...

def get_settings(userIds:list[int])->pd.DataFrame:
   if isinstance(userIds, int): userIds=[userIds]
   ...

def get_devices(userIds:list[int])->pd.DataFrame:
   ...
```

In the example above, I could get the usernames by running `get_username(38)` or `get_username([38,39,40])`. But running `get_devices(38)` results in an error later in the code because it's not being cast into a list.

Is there any Python feature that can make this code more DRY?

Comment: You could use a decorator for this.

Comment: Extending on decorator idea, maybe consider using a library for runtime type checking?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert only the first parameter of a function, you can use a decorator:

```py
def wrap_list(f):
    def _(x, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return f([x], *args, **kwargs)
        return f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

Then use it like this:

```
@wrap_list
def f(x):
    print(x)
    
f(1)         # Outputs [1]
f([1, 2])    # Outputs [1, 2]
```

You can read more about decorators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/9997212).